# horizontally scrolling flex child

Tags: css, flexbox

I have been scowering the web, but can not seem to get a solution to work.

Here is an example codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wxjjqp

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.horizontally-scrolled-items {
  display: flex;
  background: lightblue;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.item {
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="horizontally-scrolled-items">
    <div class="item">item1</div>
    <div class="item">item2</div>
    <div class="item">item3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="aside">
    <button>keep me on screen</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is for horizntally-scrolled-items to be flex:1. If the items are greater than the width of the container, for them to scroll, leaving aside in the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with `min-width`. Give your `.item` class a `min-width` with a `flex-grow: 1;`. Then set your `.horizontally-scrolled-items` div to `width: 100%;`.

**CSS**

```
.horizontally-scrolled-items {
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  min-width: 400px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/bZWRbg)

Answer (score 5):

**With Flex box**

```
.horizontally-scrolled-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

**Without Flex box**

```
.horizontally-scrolled-items {
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
.item {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set the items with and `flex: 0 0 auto` which is short hand for `flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0`, so flexbox does not try to resize the items.