# Horizontally scroll a list within flexbox a layout with set-width sidebar

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, horizontal-scrolling

I have a two-column layout with a tabbed UI in the main section and a sidebar attached to the right-side. On larger screens, the width of the main column is fluid while the width of the sidebar should be set. On smaller screens, the sidebar should reposition underneath the main section, with both the main and sidebar sections being 100% wide.

I'm trying to build the tabbed UI so that it scrolls horizontally when the main section isn't wide enough to display all of its tabs. The problem I'm running into is that, when the screen can't fit all of the tabs, the sidebar is being pushed off of the screen to the right, which triggers a horizontal scroll on the entire page, and also *doesn't* trigger a horizontal scroll bar on the tabbed UI.

I assume that this happens because flexbox is giving priority to the space in the main column and isn't forcing the scrollbar.

In my Codepen example, I'm using Bootstrap's grid and using the mobile-first approach. Setting min-width breakpoint of 1000px (around line 29 of the CSS) causes the sidebar to reposition under the main content and allows the tabs to scroll horizontally. Unfortunately, I don't think this will work for me, as my layout won't have a set number of tabs.

You can view my progress in my codepen: 
https://codepen.io/scobban/pen/pVqeKR

The only other post that I've found that relates closely to my issue is [horizontally scrolling flex child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132523/horizontally-scrolling-flex-child), but it hasn't seemed to help me.

Thanks for your help.

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <header class="header">
    Header Nav Bar
  </header>
  <div class="l-flex">
    <div class="l-main">
      <h1>Main</h1>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li>
          <a class="tab">Pizzas</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Subs</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a class="tab">Salads</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Entress</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Daily Specials</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Side Dishes</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Toppings</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Dressings</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Utensils</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="l-side l-side-right">
      <div class="l-side-section">
        <h2>Sidebar</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my scss:**

```
$light: lightblue;
$shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
$navheight: 51px;

.header {
  background-color: black;
  height: $navheight;
}

.l-flex {
  display: display;
}
.l-main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 2em;
  flex: 1;
}
.l-side {
  flex: 0 0 21em;
  background-color: $light;
  .l-side-section {
    padding: 1em 2em;
  }
  &.l-side-right {
    box-shadow: inset 6px 0px 6px -6px $shadow;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .l-flex {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.nav-tabs {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in your HTML and CSS and it is working fine without mobile-first approach-

```css
$light: lightblue;
$shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
$navheight: 51px;

.header {
  background-color: black;
  height: $navheight;
}

.l-flex {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.l-main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 2em;
  min-width:calc(100% - 21em);
  max-width: 100%;    
}
.l-side {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: $light;
  .l-side-section {
    padding: 1em 2em;
  }
  &.l-side-right {
    box-shadow: inset 6px 0px 6px -6px $shadow;
  }
}



.nav-tabs {
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
  }
}

.tabs-container{
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  min-width:calc(100% - 21em);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <header class="header">
    Header Nav Bar
  </header>
  <div class="l-flex">
    <div class="l-main">
      <h1>Main</h1>
      <div class="tabs-container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li>
          <a class="tab">Pizzas</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Subs</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a class="tab">Salads</a>         </li>
        <li><a class="tab">Entress</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Daily Specials</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Side Dishes</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Toppings</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Dressings</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab">Utensils</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="l-side l-side-right">
      <div class="l-side-section">
        <h2>Sidebar</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

link- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRXYyd
Hope this help.

Happy coding.